# How do I display just one sql field using php?

Tags: php, sql

lets say I have a single record with fields; id, username and password inside of a database. how do I use php to display the username from the first record field without using a while, for or if loop?

Can some write a script for me please?

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
?>
<?php

echo "your name is " . $name. "<br>";
echo "your email address is " . $email. "<br>";

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
echo = $result->username;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

this is the config.php file

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'users');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Query the Database with a WHERE clause and LIMIT 1 then use something like $data = $query->fetchObject(). You should google PHP with MySQL PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: can you write a script for me please, I am only new..

Comment: Use the SELECT statement to limit the columns you want to return too. You probably don't want to return the password in most cases and it should be hashed anyway.

Comment: would this work?? 
<?php

$sql  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

echo = $result;
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO for prepared statements:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Database Username";
$password = "Database Password";
$dbname = "Database Name";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then Run your SQL query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM yourTableName LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute();
$username = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo $username[0];
//Or foreach($username as $name){echo $name;}
```

## That code should be wrapped inside php tags `<?php //the code ?>`

UPDATE from comments it showed up that you are using MYSQLI, SO you should use something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "DBname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT username from users ORDER by username DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

echo $result->username;
```